Different results while employing a pre-trained WE with Keras
I am just stucked with a puzzle. Any help would be greatly appreciated! Suppose I have a pre-trained Word Embedding dataset and I want to fit a dense NN. I have basically two options:
OPTION A: I can define a model like the one below. Note that: I have specified mask_zero=TRUE; I am freezing the WE weights; I am adding a  layer_global_average_pooling_1d ()
tensorflow::set_random_seed(123)
model1 <- keras_model_sequential() %>%layer_embedding(input_dim = max_features,output_dim = embedding_dim,input_length = ncol(data2), mask_zero=TRUE, trainable = FALSE) %>%
layer_global_average_pooling_1d () %>%layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu") %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

Model1
____________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                Output Shape                            Param #        Trainable
===============================================================================================================
embedding_3 (Embedding)                     (None, 1125, 100)                       1127900        N
global_average_pooling1d_3 (GlobalAverageP  (None, 100)                             0              Y
ooling1D)
dense_11 (Dense)                            (None, 32)                              3232           Y
dense_10 (Dense)                            (None, 1)                               33             Y
===============================================================================================================
Total params: 1131165 (4.32 MB)
Trainable params: 3265 (12.75 KB)
Non-trainable params: 1127900 (4.30 MB)
compile(model1loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = 'rmsprop',metrics = 'accuracy')

history1 <-  fit(model1, x=data2,y=y,epochs = 10,batch_size = 20)

OPTION B: I can compute the average of the vectors of all the words included in each texts of my corpus along the dimensions of my pre-trained WE dataset to represent the text in the same embedding world than the features (basically what layer_global_average_pooling_1d () does inside model1 - if I am not wrong). After having done it and having therefore created my matrix with: number of rows=documents of the corpus; number of columns=dimensions of my pre-trained WE dataset, I could fit the following model:
tensorflow::set_random_seed(123)
model2 <- keras_model_sequential() %>%
layer_dense(units = 32, activation = "relu", input_shape =  ncol(embed2)) %>%
layer_dense(units = 1, activation = "sigmoid")

Model2
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                                    Output Shape                                 Param #
===============================================================================================================
dense_8 (Dense)                                 (None, 32)                                   3232
dense_9 (Dense)                                 (None, 1)                                    33
===============================================================================================================
Total params: 3265 (12.75 KB)
Trainable params: 3265 (12.75 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)
_______________________________________________________________________________________________________________
Total params: 3265 (12.75 KB)
Trainable params: 3265 (12.75 KB)
Non-trainable params: 0 (0.00 Byte)

compile(model2,loss = 'binary_crossentropy',optimizer = 'rmsprop',metrics = 'accuracy')

history2 <-  fit(model2, embed2,y=y,epochs = 10,batch_size = 20)

Now, these two models produce largely different results. But, as far as I get, it shouldn't be the case! Basically, they are the same model!
Any ideas of why? BestLuigi
